# Configuration manager shouldn't be null error

Tags: struts2, glassfish

we have a WAR that has S2 code in it and the WAR is deployed on Glassfish.  We are noticing `the configuration manager shouldn't be null` error when we deploy the code and try to bring use the application (in browser).  The error does not happen when the Application server is restarted after the deployment.
Log:

```
[#|2009-12-04T12:55:47.215-0500|SEVERE|sun-appserver2.1|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig|_ThreadID=48;_ThreadName=RMI TCP Connection(5846)-127.0.0.1;_RequestID=d8d812b6-c1e1-4b56-a707-68e071ffb9e9;|ApplicationFilterConfig.doAsPrivilege
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The configuration manager shouldn't be null
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:849)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.cleanup(Dispatcher.java:256)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.destroy(FilterDispatcher.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
```

I researched this issue a bit and [found](https://issues.apache.org/struts/browse/WW-2523) that this is an error with S2.  Even though, bug is fixed (last comment) that fix does not work for us.  Maybe because glassfish server is not mentioned in the ticket.

Has anyone faced similar issues?...or has a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed if [ActionContextCleanup](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ActionContextCleanUp.html) Filter is added to web.xml.  It worked for my on GlassFish V2.  [FilterDispatcher](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/FilterDispatcher.html) is suppose to clean up actions but this dispatcher seems to have some issues on GlassFish V2.  So ActionContextCleanup Filter should be used with url pattern that matches your struts pages.